# Java creating Objects inside an Object

Tags: java, class, object

I'm quite new to Java and I wanted to program chess on my own. Already created a field, player and piece class for that, tho only the piece, player and main class are important for this. So basically I wanted to create an object of Piece inside an Object of Player. Tried it and didn't work :,)

Basically I defined constructor methods both for Piece and Player. Using Main, I created objects Player 1 and 2. Then I wanted to try if I could create an Object of Piece inside the Player class/Object by using a method that creates that Piece Object. Using that I wanted to directly assign the pieces to the Players. In that case here only one pawn tho.
Btw I only pasted the most important stuff from the file so not the stuff associated with the field or smth.

```
class Player {
    public int id, piecesleft, l1, l2;
    public String name;
    
    public Player(int idin, int plin, String namein) {
        id = idin;
        piecesleft = plin;
        name = namein;
        if (id == 1) {
            l1 = 7;
            l2 = 6;
        } else {
            l1 = 0;
            l2 = 1;
        }
    };

    public void piecegen() {
        Piece pawnA = new Piece('p', true, l2, 0);
    };
};

class Piece {
    public char type;
    public boolean status;
    public int pos1, pos2;
    
    public Piece(char typein, boolean statusin, int pos1in, int pos2in) {
        type = typein;
        status = statusin;
        pos1 = pos1in;
        pos2 = pos2in;
    };
};

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("\nSpieler 1 - Name:  ");
        String name1 = scan.nextLine();
        Player p1 = new Player(1, 16, name1);
        
        System.out.print("Spieler 2 - Name:  ");
        String name2 = scan.nextLine();
        Player p2 = new Player(2, 16, name2);
        
        p1.piecegen();
        p2.piecegen();
        System.out.println(p1.pawnA.type);
    };
};
```

basically tells me "pawnA cannot be resolved or is not a field" :,)

Comment: The error message is quite clear. `pawnA` is not a field of `Player`. You have a *local variable*  with that name in the `piecegen()` method, but no such field.

Comment: if you look at the *`Player` class* there is no `pawnA` *field*. Variables in the `main()` function or anywhere else have nothing to do with it. `p1.pawnA` doesn’t exist. Simple as that. @HeathMorgan

Comment: @HeathMorgan And I didn't say anything about there being 'no variable named `pawnA` in the `main` function. Don't misquote me. You're just confusing the issue. There is no need to re-explain what has already been stated clearly. Your comments are all misleading and should be deleted.

Comment: so uhm how can I do that now? so how could I create the pawnA as some kind of object for Player so that I can interact with those Pieces like with "p1.pawnA.type"? My first thought would be to define public variables for type, posx etc. for each Piece inside the piecegen function... does that make sense or smth? :,)

Comment: Same way as you declared `id, piecesLeft, l1, l2, name`.

Comment: Yea I solved it by creating an Array of Piece-Objects inside the player class xD. Thanks for the help tho :)

Comment: @user207421 I apologize, since Paradox is clearly a newbie, I was trying to further explain in a different way that might help.  My comment was trying to clarify how the scope of the local variable does not extend outside of that function.  The error message is clear to you and me, but they do not understand, so simply restating that there is "no such field" may not be as helpful.  I do not think it is misleading to add that a local variable inside one function is not visible elsewhere, so I'll restate it again in the hopes it helps Paradox.

Comment: @HeathMorgan I’m not complaining about helpfulness. I’m complaining about you posting one mistake after another, and about attributing to me statements which I have not made. And nowhere did you state what you now claim you are restating.

Answer (score 0):

Yea I'm answering my own question now cus I found a solution. Maybe It'll help some other newbies :)
Like I said what I wanted to do was to create Objects inside the Object. Realising, that doesn't really work, I tried other stuff and found a solution. In that case I wanted to create pieces and directly associate them with the player. I just had to think a lil bit different. Found out, I can just create an Array of Objects for the Pieces class, inside the Player class:

```
public Piece piece[] = new Piece[16];
```

thats what I pasted in the beginning of the Player class, making the array part of the player. the "Piece" after public is just declaring the type of the array. It basically tells the program that this is an array of Objects from the "Piece" class. "piece[]" is the name of the array. with "new Piece[16]" we tell the program how many objects of "Piece there can be inside the Array. In the end I just edited my "piecegen()" method in the player class to set the value on a specific place inside the array, to an object of piece with the Parameters I wanted. Example from the method:

```
this.piece[0] = new Piece('p', true, l2, 0);
```

Now I can access the objects inside the main method by just accessing the array and the point inside the array and add ".type" ore something like that like with any normal object. Example from my Main method:

```
System.out.println("| Type: " + p1.piece[0].type);
```

This would output "p" because it's a pawn :)
Thanks for the comments tho and correct me if anything in this answer is wrong pls. In the end I'm still no expert ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to the scope of the pawnA variable. In your Player class, you've defined pawnA as a local variable inside the piecegen() method. This means that pawnA is only accessible within the piecegen() method and cannot be accessed outside of it.

If you want to create a Piece object for each player and have it accessible as a member of the Player class, you should declare pawnA as an instance variable within the Player class.

```
class Player {
    public int id, piecesleft, l1, l2;
    public String name;
    public Piece pawnA; // Declare pawnA as an instance variable

    public Player(int idin, int plin, String namein) {
        id = idin;
        piecesleft = plin;
        name = namein;
        if (id == 1) {
            l1 = 7;
            l2 = 6;
        } else {
            l1 = 0;
            l2 = 1;
        }
        pawnA = new Piece('p', true, l2, 0); // Initialize pawnA
    }
}
```

Now, you should be able to access pawnA from the Player object as shown in your Main class.